# esp8266(ESP-01) maximum number of messages/sec

Tags: performance, esp8266

I need to use the wifi module in the header to forward packets.
It is assumed that this will be at least 1000 packets per second with a length of 11 bytes. I used an example from the Arduino library to test how many messages can be sent over WiFi and got about 300-400 messages per second, which is fatally low.
Question:
Is there a way to achieve the message sending speed I need using the ESP-01? If not - why and what are the Wi-Fi modules capable of doing this?

My speed test script looks like this:

```
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <WiFiUdp.h>

    #ifndef APSSID
    #define APSSID "ESPap"
    #define APPSK "thereisnospoon"
    #endif

    /* Set these to your desired credentials. */
    const char *ssid = APSSID;
    const char *password = APPSK;

    WiFiUDP   _udp;
    IPAddress _remoutIP     { 192, 168, 4, 255 };
    uint32_t  _remoutePort  { 45454 };

    void setup() {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.begin(115200);
        while (!Serial)
        { };

        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Configuring access point...");
        WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

        IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
        Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
        Serial.println(myIP);

        if (_udp.begin(_remoutePort))
        {
            Serial.print("UDP start listening to the port: ");
            Serial.println(_udp.localPort());
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("UDP failed.");
        }
    }

    uint8_t buff[]        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    uint32_t errors       { 0 };
    uint32_t succes       { 0 };
    uint32_t elapsedTime  { 0 };

    void loop()
    {
        _udp.beginPacket(_remoutIP, _remoutePort);
        _udp.write(buff, 8);
        if (_udp.endPacket())
            ++succes;
        else
            ++errors;

        if ((millis() - elapsedTime) > 1000)
        {
            elapsedTime = millis();

            Serial.print("Succes/Errors udp pacet sending: ");
            Serial.print(succes);
            Serial.print("/");
            Serial.println(errors);
    
            succes = 0;
            errors = 0;

        }
    }
```

P.S:
The packets must be sent exactly as described above - each message is separate, 11 bytes each, since I need to see the recipient's response in real time.

Comment: "fatally low", judging from what you described, it is likely that you are not aware of what you are dealing with. Typical IP headers for IPV4 are 20 bytes, UDP headers are 8 bytes. So even you are sending one byte, there are more than what appears to be get sent. If you are having packet data with 8 bytes only, then UDP might not be something you should use. IP layer has a MTU of 1500 bytes, which means that when running UDP, 1472 bytes can be used for the payload, so for longer message, the overhead is not that bad. Theoretical WiFi throughput for 802.11a and 802.11g is 54 Mbps.

Comment: Having said that, your implementation is not correctly done, I'm able to achieve 115k packets/second, which is still way low than the theoretical number. This is due to the limitation of the WIFiUDP library, 1) On AVR based boards, outgoing UDP packets are limited to 72 bytes in size. For non-AVR boards the limit is 1446 bytes. 2) the udp.write() doesn't actually send out the data, but udp.endPacket() does, what this means that the setup and teardown the UDP connection cost a lot of overhead.